# C++ derived class member is ambiguous

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, template-classes

I have 3 classes, A, B, C.

A and B both have a protected member, let's call it x. It's a pointer.

C inherits from both A and B.

Question: Does C have its own copy of x now? If not, what does x mean now, B::x or A::x?
How can C access its own x?

Btw, A and B are actually created using a template class so C looks like this:

```
class C : public A<someType>, public B<otherType> { 
   public:
      void metod() {
         this->x = 1 // doesn't work because now the member is ambiguous.
      }
}
```

Comment: does this test compile atleast?

Comment: disambiguate it `this->A::x`

Comment: No it doesn't compile. That's the point...

Comment: The meaning of `x` (unadorned) in `C` is ambiguous, since it can equally well refer to `A::x` or `B::x`.    `C` does not have any member of its own called `x` unless you explicitly declare one.     To use them,  refer to `A::x` and `B::x`  (or `this->A::x` and `this->B::x`)  since they are distinct.    This assumes that `A::x` and `B::x` are accessible (if `A` has a `private` member named `x`, then `A::x` is inaccessible to `C` - but its name still participates in name lookup).    [Note - my description here is for the non-template `A` and `B` - adjust as appropriate for templated `A` or `B`].